多対多の関連付けをしているtest/fixturesファイルの読み込みでエラーが生じる
問題

Rails 7.1.4
Minitest

タイトル通り、中間テーブルを用いた多対多関連付けをしているfixturesファイルの読み込みでエラーが生じてしまいます。
テスト実行時のエラーの内容は以下のとおりです。
❯ rails test test/models/user_test.rb

Running 2 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 61107

# Running:

WARNING: Rails was not able to disable referential integrity.

This is most likely caused due to missing permissions.
Rails needs superuser privileges to disable referential integrity.

    cause: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_322959" is a system trigger


E

Error:
UserTest#test_.find_or_create_from_discord_info_is_used_as_create_method_if_user_is_new:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "participants" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a1f1a2f4f1"
DETAIL:  Key (reading_club_id)=(291426843) is not present in table "reading_clubs".

詳細
関連付けは、以下のようにparticipantsテーブルを中間テーブルに置いて、userとreading_clubを多対多で関連付けています。
- users *-* participants *-* reading_clubs
以下はschema.rbです。
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.1].define(version: 2024_10_03_111912) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "reading_club_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["reading_club_id"], name: "index_participants_on_reading_club_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_participants_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "reading_clubs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.boolean "finished", null: false
    t.text "template"
    t.text "read_me"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "uid", null: false
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "provider", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "participants", "reading_clubs"
  add_foreign_key "participants", "users"
end

また、fixturesファイルは以下のように書いています。
# users.yml

user1:
  uid: 12345678
  name: TestMan
  provider: discord

# reading_clubs.yml
reading_club1:
  title: ブルーベリー本輪読会
  finished: false
  template: null
  read_me: null

# participants.yml
pariticipant:
  user: user1
  reading_club: reading_club1

質問
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "participants" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a1f1a2f4f1"

このエラー文から、participantsの外部キーがうまく設定できておらず、エラーが起こっていると思っています。
原因としてはparticipantsのデータが、userやreading_clubより先に読み込まれてしまうため、外部キーにあたるデータが存在しないためだと思っています。
その場合、fixturesの読み込み順を制御する方法はあるでしょうか？
試したこと

fixtures :users, :reading_clubs, :participantsをテストに書き込む
エラーは治りませんでした。(同じエラー)

# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :users, :reading_clubs, :participants

  setup do
    ...

その他の気がかり
This is most likely caused due to missing permissions.
Rails needs superuser privileges to disable referential integrity.

    cause: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_322959" is a system trigger

このエラー文も気がかりです。
今回は以下のconfig/database.ymlのように、test・development・productionでDBを利用するユーザーを変えています。
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rindokukainote_development
  username: development
  password: development_password

test:
  <<: *default
  database: rindokukainote_test
  username: test
  password: test_password
...

特にいじらなければRailsが自動でやってくれるところ、下手にtest用のユーザーを用意したために権限が足りず今回のエラーが生じている可能性も考えています。

問題

Rails 7.1.4
Minitest

fixtures



中間テーブルを用いて、多対多の関連付けをしているモデルのfixturesファイルの読み込み時にエラーが生じてしまう。
エラー内容は以下の通り。
❯ rails test test/models/user_test.rb

Running 2 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 61107

# Running:

WARNING: Rails was not able to disable referential integrity.

This is most likely caused due to missing permissions.
Rails needs superuser privileges to disable referential integrity.

    cause: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_322959" is a system trigger

E

Error:
UserTest#test_.find_or_create_from_discord_info_is_used_as_create_method_if_user_is_new:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "participants" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a1f1a2f4f1"
DETAIL:  Key (reading_club_id)=(291426843) is not present in table "reading_clubs".

原因としては、中間テーブルの読み込み(削除)が先に行われてしまっているため、持つべき外部キーのデータが存在せずそこでエラーが生じてしまっている。
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation
が、本質的にはテスト用のDBを利用しているユーザーにSUPER USER権限がないことが問題となっている。
背景
(本来は分ける必要がないが、)
今回のRailsアプリでは、test・development・productionのpostgresqlユーザーを分けている。
以下はcongif/database.yml。
default: &default

  adapter: postgresql

  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rindokukainote_development
  username: development
  password: development_password

test:
  <<: *default
  database: rindokukainote_test
  username: test
  password: test_password

production:
  <<: *default
  database: rindokukainote_production
  username: <%= ENV["DB_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>

解決法

testユーザーにSUPER USER権限を与える

理由

参考URL：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729723/ruby-on-rails-deleting-fixtures-with-foreign-keys/32213455#32213455

一部抜粋すると、Railsがテストを実行するときにはまずテーブル内のテストデータを削除するところから始まる。
外部キー制約があるテーブルを削除する際には、削除する順番に依ってエラーが生じてしまう可能性があるため、削除前に一旦外部キー制約を無効にするSQLをたたいている。
ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;

これらのSQLにはDBユーザーにSUPER USER権限が必要となる。
今回はtest用に新たにユーザーを割り振っているため、そのユーザーにSUPER USER権限がないまま上記のSQLを実行しようとしてしまっている。
そのため、
WARNING: Rails was not able to disable referential integrity.

This is most likely caused due to missing permissions.
Rails needs superuser privileges to disable referential integrity.

    cause: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_322959" is a system trigger

permissionのエラーが出つつも、結果的に外部キー制約を無効にできないため外部キー制約に引っかかる旨のエラーも生じてしまっている。
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "participants" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a1f1a2f4f1"

